# How to disarm and correctly dispose of tear gas spray?

Tags: safety, home-experiment

I have a can of spray for self-protection which has expired way back in 2008. It hasn't been used at all, and it doesn't seem a good idea to just throw it away without disabling it somehow first. I'm looking for ways to disarm it with minimum risk to myself and others. Obviously, I can just spray it away, but I'd rather not if I can avoid it.

The active ingredient is [2-chlorobenzalmalononitrile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CS_gas).

It's not water-soluble, but I was thinking of some combination of cooking oil and alkaline agent (baking soda, for example) to neutralize it. I'm still doing research on it, and I won't be doing anything rash just yet :-)

Any particular advice how to neutralize this spray?

If jurisdiction is somehow important, assume European Union.

Answer (score 4):

**Do not open, do not try to neutralize it yourself!** Bring it to **Recycling center** (*DE*: Wertstoffhof). If your city is 100k+ there should be one. That's the place where you bringing your old furniture, the rubbish after renovations, and so on. They have a part for disposal of **hazardous waste** (*DE*: Sondermüll). What usually comes in there are paints, old car batteries, old pesticides, *etc...*. Another possibility - if you have some friend at chemistry school of some local university, give it him. Each Chemistry faculty has some "disposal" facility.

Comment: Good idea about Chemistry faculty, we have one in the university. I have to check with them if they can take care of this.